# jsdoc comments are not automatically generated in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

jsdoc comments are not automatically generated in visual studio.

(not vscode)


After updating Visual Studio, JavaScript's jsdoc style comments are not automatically generated.

[image: the current situation]

Before the update, it was created automatically when you type "/**".

[image: in normal operation]

A search describes this as a bug that existed a long time ago.

But I'm on the latest version.

[image: my version of visual studio]

What are some things that I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Visual Studio and it seemed like the issue was resolved.
However, the same thing happens again when I load the backed up settings.

There are several articles saying that this happened after updating Visual Studio.
Judging from this, it is suspected that the configuration file is twisted when updating.

Problem is, I haven't been able to find out which setting is causing this.

--   addition ---

After several reinstalls, I found the cause.

- TextEdit > JavaScript/TypeScript > General > Settings > Automatic Braces Completion
- Disabling this option will prevent this feature from working.

Originally, it worked regardless of this option, so I think it's a bug in Visual Studio.   

  

    
Depending on the version, other options may cause this error.   
    
If the problem is solved when you initialize the option, you can judge that there is a bug related to the option you were using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this problem has been driving me crazy for a few weeks !